# My computer is stuck in Ubuntu Start up screen and doesn't start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup, upstart

I got  Ubuntu 19.04 (old laptop) and my computer doesn't start. I'm not dual booting it with windows or any other Linux etc. I'm only having the Ubuntu 19 04 on it, I however got problem when starting the computer, it doesn't start, I don't know know if it's a booting problem or something just wrong with the Ubuntu or my computer could be as well. But does anyone recognize the problem? And having a salution? I'm getting stuck at the "Ubuntu start screen" where it shows Ubuntu log and loading signs   (I manually give up after 30 minutes to 1 hour each time I try)

Comment: At that screen, press ESC. Do you see any error messages?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the F1 key during the boot up process? The F1 key shows a terminal telling what Ubuntu is doing. You may find some useful information such as process failures.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help and answer, I did not fully understand what it was i should change once I got into that menu, however at last I did find an instruction to fix problems by the live CD, well, just did it, so just restarted th computer succesfully once, so lets see how it develops but I belive it might have worked. However I did as the link said, get Ubuntu by the Live CD, "as new" then press "try Ubuntu" instead of install, then just follow the commands in terminal and do as it say: 
https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-boot-repair